# How to add filter to custom API?

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

I have created a custom API taking help from [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-api-in-magento-part-one--cms-23785). Now i want to add filter to this API. Like if i want to get products filtered with some specific sku.

How can i do that?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting much time, found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24942925/2144006).

need to pass the variable in wsdl.xml file:

```
<message name="customapimoduleProductListRequest">
 <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
 <part name="customvar" type="xsd:string" /> 
</message>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below URL:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/get_filters.html

If my answer helped you, you can accept the answer so it can help others also.